# Examples of self-dual koszul algebras

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, duality-theorems

I'm looking for down-to-earth examples of self-dual koszul algebras. That is, algebras for which the ext algebra is isomorphic to the algebra itself. There is an example in the beginning of the BGS article (link http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-02/S0894-0347-96-00192-0/S0894-0347-96-00192-0.pdf) which I unfortunately don't understand since I don't know any Lie theory.

Are there simpler examples? Ideally ones you can write down in generators & relations form.

Comment: How about the tensor product of a polynomial algebra on one generator with an exterior algebra on one generator? (Or $n$ generators for each.)

Comment: That's a great example, thanks! So do all self-dual algebras arise this way, $A\otimes A^{!}$? @Johnpalmieri

Comment: I don't know if all self-dual algebras arise that way, but it's a good way to produce examples.